# Pandas DataFrame.groupby() to dictionary with multiple columns for value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, jupyter

```
type(Table)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Table
======= ======= =======
Column1 Column2 Column3
0       23      1
1       5       2
1       2       3
1       19      5
2       56      1
2       22      2
3       2       4
3       14      5
4       59      1
5       44      1
5       1       2
5       87      3
```

For anyone familliar with pandas how would I build a multivalue dictionary with the `.groupby()` method?

I would like an output to resemble this format:

```
{
    0: [(23,1)]
    1: [(5,  2), (2, 3), (19, 5)]
    # etc...
    }
```

where `Col1` values are represented as keys and the corresponding `Col2` and `Col3` are tuples packed into an array for each `Col1` key.

My syntax works for pooling only one column into the `.groupby()`:

```
Table.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply(list).to_dict()
# Result as expected
{
    0: [23], 
    1: [5, 2, 19], 
    2: [56, 22], 
    3: [2, 14], 
    4: [59], 
    5: [44, 1, 87]
}
```

However specifying multiple values for the indices results in returning column names for the value :

```
Table.groupby('Column1')[('Column2', 'Column3')].apply(list).to_dict()
# Result has column namespace as array value
{
    0: ['Column2', 'Column3'],
    1: ['Column2', 'Column3'],
    2: ['Column2', 'Column3'],
    3: ['Column2', 'Column3'],
    4: ['Column2', 'Column3'],
    5: ['Column2', 'Column3']
 }
```

How would I return a list of tuples in the value array?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Customize the function you use in `apply` so it returns a list of lists for each group:

```
df.groupby('Column1')[['Column2', 'Column3']].apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist()).to_dict()
# {0: [[23, 1]], 
#  1: [[5, 2], [2, 3], [19, 5]], 
#  2: [[56, 1], [22, 2]], 
#  3: [[2, 4], [14, 5]], 
#  4: [[59, 1]], 
#  5: [[44, 1], [1, 2], [87, 3]]}
```

If you need a list of tuples explicitly, use `list(map(tuple, ...))` to convert:

```
df.groupby('Column1')[['Column2', 'Column3']].apply(lambda g: list(map(tuple, g.values.tolist()))).to_dict()
# {0: [(23, 1)], 
#  1: [(5, 2), (2, 3), (19, 5)], 
#  2: [(56, 1), (22, 2)], 
#  3: [(2, 4), (14, 5)], 
#  4: [(59, 1)], 
#  5: [(44, 1), (1, 2), (87, 3)]}
```

Comment: This is great, so the `apply` method is basically a `map` and `reduce` bundled into one?

Comment: `apply` method is close to `map`, both simulate for loops. The `reduce` effect in this example is more due to `groupby`. Semantically, `apply` invokes the lambda function for each group.

Answer (score 8):

One way is to create a new `tup` column and then create the dictionary.

```
df['tup'] = list(zip(df['Column2'], df['Column3']))
df.groupby('Column1')['tup'].apply(list).to_dict()

# {0: [(23, 1)],
#  1: [(5, 2), (2, 3), (19, 5)],
#  2: [(56, 1), (22, 2)],
#  3: [(2, 4), (14, 5)],
#  4: [(59, 1)],
#  5: [(44, 1), (1, 2), (87, 3)]}
```

[@Psidom's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017309/9209546) is more efficient, but if performance isn't an issue use what makes more sense to you:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

def jp(df):
    df['tup'] = list(zip(df['Column2'], df['Column3']))
    return df.groupby('Column1')['tup'].apply(list).to_dict()

def psi(df):
    return df.groupby('Column1')[['Column2', 'Column3']].apply(lambda g: list(map(tuple, g.values.tolist()))).to_dict()

%timeit jp(df)   # 110ms
%timeit psi(df)  # 80ms
```

Comment: Would it possible to modify this to have dict instead of tuples: {0: {23: 1}, 1: {5: 2, 2: 3, 19: 5}, 2: {56: 1, 22: 2} } ?

Comment: @user1298416, take the output `dct` and use a comprehension: `{k: dict(v) for k, v in dct.items()}`. `dict` takes a list of tuples directly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for row in df.values.tolist():
    d[row[0]].append(tuple(row[1:]))

dict(d)

{0: [(23, 1)],
 1: [(5, 2), (2, 3), (19, 5)],
 2: [(56, 1), (22, 2)],
 3: [(2, 4), (14, 5)],
 4: [(59, 1)],
 5: [(44, 1), (1, 2), (87, 3)]}
```